# Dynamic marker and infoWindow Google Maps API using Google App Engine parsing through a JSON file

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Hi I'm new to stackoverflow (and coding) but I am working on a web-application where I want to add dynamic markers and infowindows based on an extracted JSON file. There are over 200 markers, so they need to be dynamic. I have code that works to add markers but as soon as I add infoWindows it doesn't. Can anybody see why? The output dropped to just one marker and no infoWindow.

Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {

  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 26.967,
    lng: -99.25
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://us-central1-cloud-calendar-project.cloudfunctions.net/InfoWindow',
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data)
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      for (element in data) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: data[element].lat,
            lng: data[element].lon
          },
          map: map,
          title: element
        });

        infowindow.setContent(data[element].country);

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I saw a post on stackoverflow with a similar question and tried it that way as well but didnt get any markers.

```
function initMap() {

  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 26.967,
    lng: -99.25
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://us-central1-cloud-calendar-project.cloudfunctions.net/InfoWindow',
    success: function(data) {
      var json = data = JSON.parse(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        point = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].lat, json[i].lon);
        contentString = json[i].Country;
        addMarkers(point, contentString);
      }
    }
  });

  function addMarkers(point, contentString) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point,
      map: map
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });
    marker.push(marker);
    infos.push(infowindow);
    for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[j], 'click', function() {
        infos[j].open(map, markers[j]);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The output of my JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "AA": {
    "celsius": 32.27777777777778,
    "country": "AA",
    "day": "25",
    "lat": 12.5,
    "lon": -70.017,
    "month": "03"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to create a new Infowindow object for each marker 2) You are not setting the Infowindow content on Marker click

Comment: I get an error with the posted code: `marker is not defined` - did you look in your Javascript console for errors?

Comment: Otherwise good job for posting a complete question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code. You should read [Using Closures in Event Listeners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure).

1. You should set the infowindow content on marker click (not within the loop, as you did)
2. You should declare the `marker` variable which is missing
3. **Any** variable you are using must be declared, for example `for (element in data)` should be `for (var element in data)`

```js
function initMap() {

  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 26.967,
    lng: -99.25
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://us-central1-cloud-calendar-project.cloudfunctions.net/InfoWindow',
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data)

      console.log(data);
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      for (var element in data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: data[element].lat,
            lng: data[element].lon
          },
          map: map,
          title: element
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, element) {

          return function() {

            var content = 'Country: ' + data[element].country;
            content += '<br>Temperature (°C): ' + data[element].celsius;

            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }

        })(marker, element));
      }
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!! Very happy, been stuck on this for days... If I could just add a second question. I actually want the infowindow to show not only the country, but also the temperature and date. So something like:

"data[element].country
Temerature (C): data[element].celsius
Date: data[element].da, data[element].mo"

But for some reason only data[element].country works in the infowindow.setContent(data[element].country), if I replace it with infowindow.setContent(data[element].celsius), the marker appears on the map but the infor window is empty..

Comment: There is no reason why that wouldn't work. See my edited code (Run code snippet). I have added both country and celsius and it works fine.

Comment: Reading your comment again... You can't mix text with variables like that. You need to put text within quotes and use the `+` sign to add them. For example: `infowindow.setContent('Country: ' + data[element].country);` anyway check my updated code which shows exactly that.

Comment: Thanks again!! This works perfectly. Thanks for all of your help and I hope you enjoy the rest of your day!